# Listbox: WM_CHAR time interval for searching items

Tags: windows, winapi, listbox, user32

The [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/about-list-boxes) of `WM_CHAR` for the listbox control states this (emphasis of *short interval* is mine):

> **WM_CHAR**
> Moves  selection to the first item that begins with the character that the user typed. If the list box has the LBS_OWNERDRAW style, no action occurs. Multiple characters that are typed within a *short interval* are treated as a group, and the first item that begins with that series of characters is selected.

They mention a *short interval*.

Does anybody know if the duration of this interval can be obtained somehow?

I have an onwer draw listbox where the bahaviour described above does not occur (which is the normal documented behaviour), and I'm emulating this myself using an interval of 1.5 seconds (which seems to be more or less the duration of the *short interval*).

Everything works fine, but rather than using a hard coded duration of 1.5 seconds, I'd like to retrieve this duration from somewhere (registry, some API I'm not aware of, ...) so the interval is the one used by the default behaviour of a list box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in my test i found that ListBox use time returned by [`GetDoubleClickTime()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdoubleclicktime) and multiple it on 4.

so `interval = 4 * GetDoubleClickTime()` or `GetDoubleClickTime() << 2`.

[image]

we can test this by change double-click time with [`SetDoubleClickTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setdoubleclicktime) function
for example

```
UINT t = GetDoubleClickTime();
SetDoubleClickTime(4000);
test();
SetDoubleClickTime(t);
```

or by hook and modify `GetDoubleClickTime` return value or change asm code under debugger (for not change even temporary global windows settings). anyway change return value from `GetDoubleClickTime` have visible effect for ListBox behavior

Comment: Great answer, which tool did you use?

Comment: But which debugger?

Comment: @Jabberwocky my own. i write it by self. so it not public and have no name. only i use it